# A potential approach to the Secretary Problem?

Tags: probability

Not too long ago, I was given a version of the Secretary Problem. I eventually solved it, but the subject of this question isn't a solution that works; I would like to know whether my first approach, which I'll outline below, would have led to anything useful.

Let $S_n$ be the set of permutations of $\left \{1,...,n \right \}$. Let $F$ be the set of functions $f_i:S_n \rightarrow \left \{1,...,n \right \}$ that take permutations as inputs and return a number corresponding to a certain element in $\left \{1,...,n \right \}$. Finally, let $C:F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a "constraint" that quantifies some property about the functions. Then the Secretary Problem boils down to finding the function $f_{optimal}$ in $\left \{f_i \space| \space a \leq C(f_i) \leq b \right \}$ that maximizes the number of successes (from which the maximal probability follows). An $f_i$ is successful on a certain permutation if the index it returns is that of the maximum.

Do note that I left the specifics of $C$ vague on purpose, as I don't know what would end up working well, if anything. The only reason it's there is to add a way to enforce the fact that strategies in real life are on-line in nature, so C restricts the functions to those that correspond to real strategies.

Just to make my question clear, using the approach outlined above, is there a way to solve for (or at least get arbitrarily close to) the success probability for any n? Though, if it's less trouble, just finding a reasonable definition of $C$ would suffice as there are fast enough ways to deal with sets of functions in the way I've described.

(If this question is too unspecific, please let me know right away.)